# Programmatically mapping .NET types onto SQL Server types?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, mapping

Is there any way to programmatically map a .NET type (such as `typeof(int)`) into its corresponding SqlDbType (such as `SqlDbType.Int`)?

Comment: Some more context might help.  ASP takes care of this for you in most cases (eg when you create parameters.)  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to write two classes that handle the execution of `DbCommand`s and the creation of its `DbParameter`s respectively, hiding the database-specific details from the rest of the application. And also, I don't want to map types manually; at least, not for the case of Sql Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, tehre is no exposure of whatever method is used internally. Your best bet it your own extension method / mapping repository that uses a switch statement or a hashtable.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into The [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)?  This will do all of the mappings for you.

Comment: +1 - I was also thinking the same thing or perhaps LINQ to SQL or another ORM.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. Do the Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL support stored procedures?

Comment: ya it does support stored procedures also

Comment: It does support SPs but from my experience it is a bit like putting a tutu on a pig.

Answer (score 1):

**See Also:**

[SQL Server Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)

Comment: I wanted a function that performed those mappings, instead of me having to manually implement them. Thanks, anyway.